# TaskFactory(TaskScheduler).ContinueWhenAll starting the new task before completing prior ones

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler).StartNew(() =>
{
    new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler).ContinueWhenAll(
                    new[] { Task1, Task2,},
                    completedTasks =>
                    {
                        Funct();
                    });
});
```

Funct() is getting called before Task1 and Task2 completed

Comment: how you  realized that func was called before task1 and task2

Comment: Funct() is using results from Task1 and Task2

Comment: please post a complete code

Comment: You're misinterpreting what you see. Funct is not being called before the two tasks have completed. But it might *look* like it does. Post more code.

Comment: @user3066887 If you undelete your post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701043/read-xml-values-from-nvarchar-column-in-sql), I can give you the answer ...